# Getting error when executing https request

Tags: php, curl, https

I'm trying to get xml data from the https. When I execute or parse this request using curl it's taking so much time.

```
$url = 'https://www.iformbuilder.com/exzact/dataXML.php?';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$File = "data.xml"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'w');
fwrite($Handle, $result); 
fclose($Handle);
```

If I write `http` instead of `https` it works. I don't know what's the reason behind this.

Comment: Well that URL is needing authentication.. Where are you passing your credentials ?

Comment: I m also passing username and passowrd in that..

Comment: Without posting your full code.. we definitely can't help you. We don't have crystal balls or magic wands ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following options:

```
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla/5.0',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE      => 'fb.tmp',
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR       => 'fb.tmp',
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => 1,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => 1,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => 0,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => 0,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 60
```

You are only using one of the SSl ops.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this by writing http instead of https in URL than its working fine .whats reasone behind this that i dont know